# C# Interop PowerPoint - Set Border Weight of a Table

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

I have a table using the 'No Style, Table Grid' style however the borders are too thick. How do I programatically set the border weight for all borders in C#?

If this can't be done, how do I change the style in my potx template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For future viewers:

```
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Borders[PPT.PpBorderType.ppBorderLeft].Weight = 0.5f;
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Borders[PPT.PpBorderType.ppBorderRight].Weight = 0.5f;
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Borders[PPT.PpBorderType.ppBorderTop].Weight = 0.5f;
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Borders[PPT.PpBorderType.ppBorderBottom].Weight = 0.5f;
```

I have thrown this in a for loop after everything is added to the table:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= objTable.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    for (int col = 1; col <= objTable.Columns.Count; col++)
    {
        objTable.Cell(row, col).Borders[PPT.PpBorderType.ppBorderLeft].Weight = 0.5f;
        objTable.Cell(row, col).Borders[PPT.PpBorderType.ppBorderRight].Weight = 0.5f;
        objTable.Cell(row, col).Borders[PPT.PpBorderType.ppBorderTop].Weight = 0.5f;
        objTable.Cell(row, col).Borders[PPT.PpBorderType.ppBorderBottom].Weight = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to also set the color of the borders to black to make them visible.